# Oracle 10g SQL: Return true if a column has only a value, but > 1 rows in a table

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to check a table if a column has only one value but multiple rows in a table??

For example:

```
ID        Reference        Status       
1         28910293         900
2         28910293         920
3         28910293         930
```

This will return true because the column(Reference) has only one value but multiple rows

```
ID        Reference        Status       
1         28910293         900
2         28910293         920
3         28910293         930
4         28910291         900
```

This will return false because the column(Reference) has 2 values.

Comment: . . A note about English.  You are using the word "a" to mean the same thing as "one", which is hard to understand.  For instance, you mean "has only one value but multiple rows".

Comment: Ok, noted, thanks for your remind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want an aggregation with a case statement.  The following query checks for multiple values (assuming no NULLs):

```
select (case when count(distinct Reference) = 1 then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end)
from t
```

If you really need the multiple rows as well:

```
select (case when count(distinct Reference) = 1 and count(*) > 1 then 'TRUE'
             else 'FALSE'
        end)
from t
```